# Customizing event appearance primefaces schedule

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I'm using the Primefaces Schedule component to render events in my web app. But i need to do a little trick with him. For each rendered event i need to show a tooltip with event details. Using the window.onload listener and some jquery functions is easy to display the tooltips of the current date frame. But, since the schedule uses ajax to display the next date frame when i press the next and prev buttons, the tooltip crashes. I've tried using the:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    // create bubble popups
    $('.fc-event-inner.fc-event-skin').CreateBubblePopup( options );
}, false);
```

But seems that it requires too much processing and the page gets slow. There is some other way to add the tooltips to each event rendered?

Comment: don't you use jquery `delegate` or `on` ? to bind those tooltips ? something like `$(document).delegate(".fc-event-inner.fc-event-skin", "hover", function (event) {if( event.type === 'mouseenter' )  {$('.fc-event-inner.fc-event-skin').CreateBubblePopup( options );}});`

Comment: @Daniel Thanks man! But the 'hover' event just fires when the mouse goes out of the div. I changed to 'mouseover' event but this doesn't fires. I need the tooltip when the mouse is over the div.

Comment: it should enter fired twice , once for `mouseenter` and second for `mouseleave` try only `.fc-event-inner` or only `.fc-event-skin` `$(document).delegate(".fc-event-inner", "hover", function (event) {
 if( event.type === 'mouseenter' ) {
  $('.fc-event-inner.fc-event-skin').CreateBubblePopup( options );
 }
 else{
        //hide?
 }
});`

Comment: @Daniel He only fires the 'mouseleave' event. What might be happening?

Comment: maybe its being "hijacked" somehow...  try the following three `mouseenter` `mouseover` `mouseover`

Comment: @Daniel This didn't work! When i use the javascript console and type the code `$(document).delegate(".fc-event-inner", "mouseenter mouseover", function(event){
                        alert('DEBUG ' + event.type);
                    });` it works! But in the javascript of the page, he doesn't works!

Comment: Cause you should run this coad on jquery load. try ....

Comment: @Daniel Did you mean `$(function(){ MYCODE });` or `$(document).load(function(){ MYCODE });`? The code is already inside the `$(function(){ });`.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $(document).delegate(".fc-event-inner", "mouseenter mouseover", function(event){
       $('.fc-event-inner.fc-event-skin').CreateBubblePopup( options );

   });
});
```

---

**Update**

I had this feeling that somewhere in the scheduler js file they doing `stopPropagation()` on `mouseover`...

look at the following piece of code from ther js file located at *primefaces-3.4.1-sources\META-INF\resources\primefaces\schedule*

```
/* Event Element Binding
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


function lazySegBind(container, segs, bindHandlers) {
    container.unbind('mouseover').mouseover(function(ev) {
        var parent=ev.target, e,
            i, seg;
        while (parent != this) {
            e = parent;
            parent = parent.parentNode;
        }
        if ((i = e._fci) !== undefined) {
            e._fci = undefined;
            seg = segs[i];
            bindHandlers(seg.event, seg.element, seg);
            $(ev.target).trigger(ev);
        }
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

**So...**

Try to remove `ev.stopPropagation();`

By the way , know that the scheduler is actually a [FullCalendar jQuery plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) , so you might find some usefull information if you google for *fullcalendar tooltip*

Here is the link for the modified [Primefacess 3.4 jar](http://2shared.com/file/SOAvwgbL/primefaces-34.html) (no `stopPropagation` for scheduler events)

Comment: Oh my God!! This just doesn't works! I've tested in Chrome and Safari but it doesn't works anyway. But the `click` event works!

Comment: Ohh man, thank you! But how can i edit the schedule js file? It's possible to edit the resources inside the primefaces jar?

Comment: just take it from the sources zip , modify it and place it inside your curent jar (using rar or 7zip) , you can add `console.log("test")` to see if the new file is the one that being used (ctrl + f5 to refresh it...)

Comment: Every time i extract the content of primefaces-3.4.jar into a folder primefaces-3.4 and edit the schedule.js inside it, when i compact the folder primefaces-3.4 into primefaces-3.4.zip and then rename it to primefaces-3.4.jar, the project doesn't build. He says that some packages of primefaces doesn't exists.

Comment: no need to extract the content of primefaces-3.4.jar , just open it (view its content) with 7zip , than delete the schedule.js , and than drag and drop into that same view the modified schedule.js

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X. I used the Zipeg, but seems that it can't save the file after edited!

Comment: I commented it out and placed `console.log("no ev.stopPropagation()");` grab it from here http://www.2shared.com/file/SOAvwgbL/primefaces-34.html let me know if its good, but I wonder what was the reason for them to use that `stopPropagation()`...

Comment: THANKS man! You don't even imagine how much you helped me! THANKS THANKS! :)