# Edit javascript associated file of primefaces schedule component

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm using schedule component of Primefaces 2.2.1. If you decompress *primefaces-2.2.1.jar* included in your project in */lib*, you see a *.js* file and a *.css* file for each component of primefaces. In my case, I have *schedule.js* and *schedule.css* (placed at *primefaces-2.2.1\META-INF\resources\primefaces\schedule*). The point is that I have to modify *schedule.js* to add some functionality. So, I decompress *primefaces-2.2.1.jar*, modify *schedule.js*, compress everything again to *primefaces-2.2.1.jar* an place it again in */lib*. Then I run the application and this message is showed to me:

*javax.servlet.ServletException: Error loading theme, cannot find "themes/sam/theme.css" resource of "primefaces" library*

I can see that the file *theme.css* is present in *primefaces-2.2.1\META-INF\resources\primefaces\themes\sam*

And I know that it's possible to change *schedule.js* and make it work becouse some other user did. You can see it here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15163&p=80971#p80971

Anybody knows how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is :

1) Install [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

2) Browse the *primefaces-2.2.1.jar* , copy the relevant js file outside the jar

3) Modify it as you wish

4) Delete the relevant js file from the jar

5) Drag and Drop the modified js file back to the jar

---

Also , take a look at a similar question :

[Customizing event appearance primefaces schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728215/customizing-event-appearance-primefaces-schedule/12735969#12735969)